# "Must declare the scalar variable" inside where clause for declared table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying out below:

```
--create temporary table
declare @tempemp TABLE(
  salary int
);

--get maximum salary of employees in sbi
insert into @tempemp
  select MAX(salary) as 'salary' from employee where company='sbi';
```

Now I want to get names of all employees who earn more than all employees of sbi. I tried this:

```
select * from employee where employee.salary > @tempemp.salary;
```

But this gives me error:

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@tempemp".
```

while this works perfectly fine:

```
select * from @tempemp;
```

when executed along with first two (declare and insert) queries.

Comment: You are using it like a scalar value with `employee.salary > @tempemp.salary`.  Is there only one row in the `@tempemp` table?  It has only one column so you can't join it to `employee`, but in th eway you're currently using it you would need `employee.salary > (select salary from @tempemp...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a table, use a variable:

```
declare @salary int;

select @salary = MAX(salary)
from employee
where company = 'sbi';

select *
from employee
where employee.salary > @salary;
```

If you do use a table, you need a subselect:

```
select *
from employee
where employee.salary > (select salary from @tempemp.salary);
```

I'm presuming that you have some reason for storing the value separately, because you could just do:

```
select *
from employee
where employee.salary > (select max(salary) from employee where company = 'sbi');
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `tablename` as `alias` in `where` clause without `selecting` it. you have to select from the table. Try this.

```
select * from employee 
where employee.salary > (select salary from @tempemp)
```